# Большое расстояние между кнопкой "Назад" и Заголовком в ToolBar (targetSdkVersion 25)

Tags: android, android-sdk

Проблема следующая. В настройках Gradle увеличил compileSdkVersion и targetSdkVersion до 25 (ранее была 23.4.0). Скачал все обновления. Также увеличил версии для требуемых библиотек до 25.0.0

И вот теперь вижу следующее в своем ToolBar:

[image: Рассояние между кнопокй Назад и Заголовком]

Кнопку назад включаю следующим образом: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

У всех такая ерунда происходит? Или я один такой "везучий"? Пробовал на версию 24 откатить, но результат такой же (только возврат на 23.4.0 помогает).

Может что-то изменилось начиная с 24 версии? Просветите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это нормальное расстояние https://material.google.com/components/cards.html#cards-usage

Comment: @iFr0z есть ли какое-то объяснение этому? Зачем оставлять столько пустующего пространства. И все-таки не дает покоя вопрос - как это пространство убрать...

Comment: ну, стандарты material design и в Африке стандарты. Только если сделать custom toolbar самому.

Comment: @iFr0z Спасибо. Действительно стандарт новый (непонятно, зачем столько пустующего места...)  Решение уже нашел. Написал ниже.

Answer (score 7):

Сам спросил, сам ответил. Это новые стандарты Material Design. Но выход есть. В layout с ToolBar добавляем app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp". Тогда все становится на свои места.

Comment: отличное решение:)